# Kubernetes: How to map 2 different pods(statefulset) to one persistense volume?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc, statefulset

How to map 2 different pods(statefulset) to one persistense volume?
We need to bind 2 pods to use one storage. Does it possible? We have the microk8s locally and create 2 manifests for two different pods, not replicas. We use dynamicly volumeClaimTemplates. But each time it creates 2 new pvc claims and pv, with different names.[image]

Comment: You can do that if you avoid `volumeClaimTemplate`. But that is a case you typically never should do, is there a good reason?

Comment: We need the statefulset because necessary save data and to after deploy it pod use the same pv. Early we have one pod but performance reasons we have separated it to 2. But the data from the first pod have to use in the second pod. This is special case. Actually I don't know if this is right to use the same pv.

Comment: But the two pods will overwrite eachothers data. The software is not designed for that situation, and then your pods must run on the same node - Avoid this! If you need multiple pods, you need an application that is designed to be **distributed** and they use their own disk, one PVC per pod.

Answer (score 0):

Check accessMode [ReadWriteMany](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) and its supported storage types (e.g. CephFS, NFS, CSI, etc.).